# How to Setup azure blob as persistent store in Open shift cluster hosted in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, persistent-storage, aro

I have an openshift cluster with version 4.4 hosted in Azure.

I need to use Azure blob storage as persistent store for pods inside my openshift cluster.

How to setup Azure blob storage as persistent volume store for Azure Openshift cluster pods ,Also How to install  CSI driver for blob storage inside Azure openshift cluster.

Can someone please provide me some reference link or any steps.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this helpful ? https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/storage_examples/azure_blob_docker_registry_example.html

Comment: @StanleyGong can you please comment on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65137145/network-policy-in-kubernetes-not-working-in-different-namespaces

Comment: Seems my friend  Charles is assisting you : )